# How to get system configuration settings Magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento

i need to retrieve my configuration settings i setup in the system.xml file of my Magento plugin.

i have setup the plugin fields in my config file and trying to retrieve them in the javscript file.is this possible?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
                <group id="custompayment" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Emipro Payment</label>
                    <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Enable</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                     <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="businessID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="65" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Business ID</label>

                </field>
                  <field id="password" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="66" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Password</label>

                </field>
                </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Below is what i've tried in my javascript file

```
define(
    [

        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',




    ],
    function (Component,$) {
        'use strict';



        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Emipro_Custompayment/payment/custompayment'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                self = this;
                this._super();

            },
            getConfigPassword: function () {
                return checkoutConfig.payment.custompayment.password;
            },
```

Comment: refer to this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125193/magento-2-get-system-config-value-in-js-file

Comment: im using a component tho. html file is my template